# Kronecker delta for multivariate distributions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

I have found a formula (Theorem 2.1 here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.4131v1.pdf) which shows the covariance matrix of a multivariate normal distribution $\Sigma_P$, but I'd like some help interpreting it, in particular what is $\delta$?:

> Let $\hat P_n$ be the maximum likelihood estimator corresponding to
>   $n$ observations $X_1,\cdots, X_n$ from a Markov chain with transition
>   probability matrix $P$. Let $(\hat P_v)n$ and $P_v$ be the vector
>   forms of $\hat P_n$ and $P$, respectively. The following theorem
>   describes the asymptotic properties of the vector $(\hat P_v)n$ as
>   $n\rightarrow \infty$.
>
> $$ \sqrt{n}\left|(\hat P_v)_n-(P_v)_n\right|\rightarrow
> > N(0,\Sigma_P)$$
>
> where $\Sigma_P$ is given by $$ (\Sigma_P )_{(ij,kl)} =
> > \delta_{ik}P_{ij}(\delta_{jl} − P_{il})$$
>
> Here, $\Sigma_P$ is a square $d^2\times d^2$ matrix. The matrix
>   element displayed corresponds to the row $j + (i − 1)d$ and the column
>   $l + (k − 1)d$.

Can you help me understand what $\delta$ is?

Answer (score 1):

By convention, $\delta_{xx}=1$ for every $x$ and $\delta_{xy}=0$ for every $x\ne y$.

In your setting, $(\Sigma_P)_{ij,ij}=P_{ij}(1-P_{ij})$ for every $(i,j)$, $(\Sigma_P)_{ij,i\ell}=-P_{ij}P_{i\ell}$ for every $i$ and every $j\ne\ell$, and $(\Sigma_P)_{ij,k\ell}=0$ for every $i\ne k$ and every $(j,\ell)$.